# Catching HttpRequestException (Connection Reset) in Async HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, exception, dotnet-httpclient

I am sometimes getting a connection reset exception when sending lots of requests. I'm not too bothered in the actual exception as I try the request later after some time, if it does encounter an error, but when using `await HttpClient.SendAsync()` I cannot seem to catch this exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I had a similar issue with request timeouts, but I found that they can be caught with the `TaskCancelledException` but does not catch the connection reset exception above.

Does anyone know how to catch this exception for an asynchronous request?

Code for Context:

```
....
            HttpResponseMessage response;

            try
            {
                response = await Program.client.SendAsync(request);
            } catch (SocketException ex) when (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionReset)
            {
                string timeoutJson = $"{{\"Error\": \"CONNECTION RESET\",{System.Environment.NewLine}\"Details\": \"{ex}\"}}";
                response = new()
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable,
                    Content = new StringContent(timeoutJson)
                };
            } catch (WebException ex) when (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
            {
                string timeoutJson = $"{{\"Error\": \"TIMEOUT\",{System.Environment.NewLine}\"Details\": \"{ex}\"}}";
                response = new()
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout,
                    Content = new StringContent(timeoutJson)
                };
            } catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                string taskCancelledJson = $"{{\"Error\": \"CANCELLED\",{System.Environment.NewLine}\"Details\": \"{ex}\"}}";
                response = new()
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout,
                    Content = new StringContent(taskCancelledJson)
                };
            } catch (WebException ex) when (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ConnectionClosed)
            {
                string closedJson = $"{{\"Error\": \"CLOSED\",{System.Environment.NewLine}\"Details\": \"{ex}\"}}";
                response = new()
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout,
                    Content = new StringContent(closedJson)
                };
            }

            return response;
```

Comment: Please show relevant code. Sounds like you need `catch (HttpRequestException ex1) when (ex1.InnerException is IOException ex2 && ex2.InnerException is SocketException ex3 && ex3.ErrorCode == 10054)`